# Best way to convert JSON DateTime values with Zero values (e.g. "0000-00-00 00:00:00")

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net, converters

Converting JSON DateTime Values with only zeros (e.g. "0000-00-00 00:00:00") does not work with the standard Json.net IsoDateTimeConverter. I developed a custom converter saving this values DateTime.MinValue. Also a DateTime.MinValue will be written as the a "ZeroDateString". All other strings are handled by the base IsoDateTimeConverter class.
I use this converter on JsonNet annotations for DateTime properties.

Is there a better, easier way to handle this, e.g. on a mor basic level, where no annotations are needed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DataLayer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom IsoDateTimeConverter for DateTime strings with zeros.
    /// 
    /// Usage Sample
    ///  [JsonConverter(typeof(ZerosIsoDateTimeConverter), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", "0000-00-00 00:00:00")]
    ///  public DateTime Zerodate { get; set; }

    /// </summary>
    public class ZerosIsoDateTimeConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The string representing a datetime value with zeros. E.g. "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string _zeroDateString;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ZerosIsoDateTimeConverter"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dateTimeFormat">The date time format.</param>
        /// <param name="zeroDateString">The zero date string. 
        /// Please be aware that this string should match the date time format.</param>
        public ZerosIsoDateTimeConverter(string dateTimeFormat, string zeroDateString)
        {
            DateTimeFormat = dateTimeFormat;
            _zeroDateString = zeroDateString;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
        /// If a DateTime value is DateTime.MinValue than the zeroDateString will be set as output value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter" /> to write to.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (value is DateTime && (DateTime) value == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                value = _zeroDateString;
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            }
            else
            {
                base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads the JSON representation of the object.
        /// If  an input value is same a zeroDateString than DateTime.MinValue will be set as return value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader" /> to read from.</param>
        /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
        /// <param name="existingValue">The existing value of object being read.</param>
        /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The object value.
        /// </returns>
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return reader.Value.ToString() == _zeroDateString
                ? DateTime.MinValue
                : base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply allow empty values in your JSON and use `DateTime?`, rather than mucking around with sentinel values? The .NET "zero date" is 0001-01-01, SQL Server doesn't allow dates before 1753-01-01, this stuff gets messy quickly.

Comment: Storing those values as nullable DateTime values will presumably the better way. That could easaly be implemented. But i still have to handle the incoming "0000... " JSON values

Comment: The date format in your the usage sample comment should probably specify the hours as a 24 hour format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue and I used a custom converter for this...

```
class MyDateConverter: Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value != null && reader.Value.ToString().StartsWith("0000")) return null;
        else return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a `ContractResolver` as explained in the documentation:

*The IContractResolver interface provides a way to customize how the JsonSerializer serializes and deserializes .NET objects to JSON without placing attributes on your classes.
Anything that can be set on an object, collection, property, etc, using attributes or methods to control serialization can also be set using an IContractResolver.*

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ContractResolver.htm

**Example:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string json = @"
{
    ""Date"": ""0000-00-00 00:00:00""
}
";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();

            var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json,
                new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new CustomDateContractResolver()});

            string serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass, Formatting.Indented,
                new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new CustomDateContractResolver()});
        }
    }

    internal class MyClass
    {
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

    internal class CustomDateContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
        {
            JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
            bool b = objectType == typeof (DateTime);
            if (b)
            {
                contract.Converter = new ZerosIsoDateTimeConverter("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", "0000-00-00 00:00:00");
            }
            return contract;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But as **@Jeroen Mostert** pointed out, you should just use the 'regular' behavior for potentially not running into trouble later and having to follow this custom logic wherever you'll use dates.